# How to create function reference that does nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

How would I reference a function that does nothing in a pythonic way?

Two way's I can think of are:

```
def nope():
     pass

fun1 = nope
fun2 = lambda: None
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: should be nope() i think

Comment: both are ok, from a better understanding the first one looks more clear, the second one shorter

Comment: @RNar. No I want to reference the function not execute it (at that moment). Somehting like a function pointer.

Comment: aahhh then yeah should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would output an informative message in case the the function was called:

```
 fun2 = lambda:"Not yet implemented"
```

If it is called the message will be outputted, if not then just a reference:

```
In [73]: fun2
Out[73]: <function __main__.<lambda>>

In [74]: fun2()
Out[74]: 'Not yet implemented'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's actually a really nice idea. I didn't put in a lot of info in my question. But in my case I have an event chain which sometimes get processed but not always. In order to break the chain I make a remove the following called function. This could of course also be handled by something like `if fun is not none: fun()`. But then again I have the feeling this would make stuff more complicated.

Comment: @magu_,  ah ok so you will want to use the value later to test against, a bit like a sentinel value?

Comment: Kind of. The thing in normal cases there is always something there to be called. In "special" cases like initializialisation or loading of new data. The callbacks should be deactivated.

Comment: The only other approach I might take if you wanted a sentinel would be to use sent = object() and use sent in the lambda but really I don't think in your case there is any one particular way

Comment: I guess you're right. In case nobody comes up with something nice in the next few days I'll accept your answer since it brings up a good point with the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get better with it. At max you can have it on the same line.

```
def nope(): pass
```